# Cython - sharing Cython modules

Tags: c++, cython

I have cython modules base.pyx and derived.pyx. `base.pyx` and its import definition `base.pxd` files are defined and is used in `derived.pyx` file using `cimport`. The files are placed [here](https://github.com/sanjaybharadwaj/Cython.git).

While using the shared object generated from cython in my Python application, the module is imported correctly, but there is always an error saying `ImportError: No module named 'base'`, when the library is used in Cpp application.

I also added the current path in my Cpp application

```
  PyObject* path = PySys_GetObject("path");
  PyObject* result = PyObject_CallMethod(path,"append","(s)",".");
  Py_XDECREF(result);
```

Even then the cython module is not visible to the application. Please let me know what can be the reason for such a path mismatch.

Comment: `.` is always in the search path. Can you try using the full path instead of `.`? Also, if the module can be imported in Python there is no reason for it not to be importable if you are using the C api of Python. Can you add more detail about your setup?

Comment: Hi Pierre, thank you for the reply, I have placed the code [here](https://github.com/sanjaybharadwaj/Cython.git). I am trying to reuse python modules in C++.

Comment: The `base.pyx` module is still not imported even after changing the search path to 'full path'.

Comment: Your setup.py only looks to build "derived.pyx"

Comment: Yeah, even if I include the `base.pyx` file in the `setup.py` and link it with the `libbase.so` file, the system is unable to `cimport` the module

Comment: Also I tried to add `PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\nsys.path.insert(0,'')");` in the cpp file. Still the system is unable to cimport the module

Comment: Ok, I understand better. All that is in base is only accessible from Python as far as it is imported by derived. The only module produced by your code is "derived" and that is all that can be imported. Two solutions: import base at the cython level in derived or make base a cythonized module on its own

Comment: 1. Importing base at Cython level in derived: This is what I have tried in the code, i have created a `base.pxd` file and tried to import that in the `derived.pyx`                                                                                                            2. Making `base` a cythonized module on its own: How can I do this? Is this different from the normal way?

Comment: 1. the question is about importing from the Python (or via the C Python API) -> you need then a Python module for base. Leading to 2: modify the setup.py so that there are two modules created: `base` and `derived`. Using `*.pyx` instead of `derived.pyx` should do but see http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html for a reference

Comment: This isn't going to help you but with Python 3.6 on Linux it works for me as written (with the C program compiled with the command ``g++ test.cpp -o test `python3-config --libs --includes` ./derived.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`` and called with `./test`)

Comment: So the follow-up question is: what platform are you using and how are you calling it?

Comment: With the edit that you made to `setup.py` three days accod I also have it working. Should I write this as answer?

Comment: I use Ubuntu17.04 with Python 3.5.3 version

Comment: The point is I do not need a normal python import. I have to import cython module using `cimport`. By using normal `ìmport` using pure python files, the code was working even before.

Comment: 1) The `cimport` does also generate a normal Python import. You can see this if you look at the generated code 2) @PierredeBuyl and I can both download the code you've provided and compile and run it without problems. 3) How are you running the program? (adding `.` to the path only works if you run it from the directory the modules are in)

Comment: Sorry if I understood badly but your aim is to "cimport" in C++? Could you edit your question to make this more precise? What you can do is "import" a cythonized module.

Comment: Then may be the way how I am compiling might be wrong :|   `1. python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace` and then i provide the LD_LIBRARY_PATH `2. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = <pwd>`, the next step is renaming the generated libraries to `libbase.so` & `libderived.so`, the next step is compiling the test application by `3. g++ test.cpp -o Test 'pkg-config --cflags --libs python3' -L. -lderived -lbase`, the application is generated and when I run the application, i get the error`No module named 'base'`

Comment: do not rename the `.so` files

Comment: For info, I do 1. `python3 setup.py build_ext` 2. `g++ -I. -I /usr/include/python3.5m -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5 build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/derived.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so test.cpp` and 3. `PYTHONPATH=build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5 ./a.out`

Comment: What I see is that there is no `lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/derived.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-‌​gnu.so` generated in the build folder. The generated shared object files are in the `Cython/` directory itself.

Comment: It was PYTHONPATH variable that was not set!! Now it is working! Thank you both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of the confusion here is about the behaviour of `cimport` - OP was trying to use a file `derived.pyx` that `cimport`ed `base.pyx` and was trying to do that from C++.

`cimport` does two things:

1. It allows Cython to know of the `cdef` functions defined in another `.pyx` or `.pxd` file, so that it can access those functions. This happens at compile time.
2. It `import`s that module. This happens at runtime and can be seen by inspecting the generated C code. The `import` is "`import`ant" for two reasons:

   1. The functions used in `base.pyx` might need global variables or classes to be initialized in base, which is done at import time.
   2. It causes the `base` shared object to be physically loaded into memory, and initializes some function pointers (in `derived`) to the `cdef` functions in `base`.

   Note that the `import` doesn't look to actually add `base` to `derived`'s module dictionary, so it isn't quite the same as a Python import.

I believe part of the thing confusing OP was this slightly unexpected `import`.

---

The second issue was only revealed on questioning, since it involved a key detail not written in the question. I managed to get the code working as supplied by doing:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
g++ test.cpp -o test `python3-config --libs --includes` ./derived.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
./test
```

(where the second line may need altering to match the exact name of the compiled derived module). @PierredeBuyl did something slightly different but similarly found that the code worked without changes.

The problem actually turned out to be that OP was renaming `derived.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and `base.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` to `libderived.so` and `libbase.so`. This wasn't a problem for `derived` which was linked directly with the `test` program but meant that the Python import mechanism couldn't find `base` (since it was renamed).

---

Posted as community wiki to disassociate myself from as much of the reputation as possible, since I think it was something of a joint effort with a somewhat unsatisfactory solution.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl - I kind of think you did more to solve this than me so if you want to write an answer yourself then I'd suggest that it should be accepted instead of this one. I thought there were some details worth putting in an answer though, even if the issue ultimately turned out to be a silly bit of renaming.

Comment: Thanks for putting an answer up :-) I have no specific desire to duplicate the work, so no issue here.